# Count times in service with worker thread in Android

Tags: android, time, service

I want to start count time in my service, when an special event occurred. And i want to do this in worker thread.
 even use `CountDownTimer()` can do this for me.
Problem is here that when i use this method in `OnHandleIntent()` of `IntentService` class, i receive an error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.CountDownTimer$1) {235e78c} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread`.

Is this the best way to count time and do special work when time arrive to destination? if not how i can? if it is, how solve? Thanks.

My service code is:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class TimeService extends IntentService {



    public TimeService(){
        super("");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        new CountDownTimer(20000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                System.out.println("Time remaining: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                System.out.println("done");
            }
        }.start();

    }



}
```

Comment: please  add codes,  so that any one can observe what's going wrong

Comment: @USKMobility necessary codes added to question.

Comment: instead of `CountDownTimer` which is used for another purposes use `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can not recommend to you to use IntentService. You should use
>   regular service.

When intent service started, it create a new worker thread and when their task is finished then it terminated. But in your case your are using Countdowntimer, that is running after termination of worker thread, so it throw exception.

One solution you can try:

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Looper.prepare();
        new CountDownTimer(20000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                System.out.println("Time remaining: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                System.out.println("done");
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }
        }.start();
      Looper.loop() ;
    }
```

Comment: Nice. I don't want to Involving many threads for a simple countdown. is this method optimized way for CPU?

Comment: Yes, Looper loops handler thread and countdowntimer in queue. For more details about looper https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/

Comment: I got this error: ` Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread`

Comment: remove Looper.prepare and then try

Comment: Nice job. my problem is resolved and I can do continue coding. thanks man.

Comment: The problem for me is Looper.myLooper() returns null and the looper is never quit. And Looper.prepare() gives me the  Only one Looper may be created per thread error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Trying using your countdown timer in Service class as 

CountDownTimer countDownTimerVariable;

In  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

 // based on your condition
if(condition)
    {
   performCountDown();
    }
}

public void performCountDown()
{
      countDownTimerVariable =  new CountDownTimer(remainingMillisForCountDown, 1000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            //Action for when the timer has finished.

                            Log.i("timer finish", "finished");
           }

   @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            //Action for every tick of the countdown.
                           //  timeCalculate((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                            Log.i("timer finish", "finished" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " Countdown");

                        }
                    };
                    countDownTimerVariable.start();
}   


   and in destroy of service

      @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.unregisterReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();

    if(countDownTimerVariable != null)
        countDownTimerVariable.cancel();
}
```

Comment: you are using service or intent service

Comment: try using Service class will fix your issue

Comment: When I use `Service` then my work do on main thread. i don't want it.